# Drawing filter banks

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw filter banks which look somehow like in the pictures below. Could you give my some hints how should I do this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: First hint: Some basic examples are given in the documentation.

Comment: I've just found the solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the package [Tikz/PGF](http://www.laqee.unal.edu.co/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) you will draw this filter banks with a simple codification. Tikz is very powerfull LaTeX package for drawing. The website [TeXample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/) contains a great compilation of examples using this package, sure it will help you. Filter Banks are as Block Diagrams, see the section [Block Diagrams](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/block-diagrams/) at TeXample for help.

For example, this code produces a simple block diagrams:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=latex']
    \tikzstyle{block} = [draw, shape=rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em, node distance=2cm, line width=1pt]
    \tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, shape=circle, node distance=1.5cm, line width=1pt, minimum width=1.25em]
    \tikzstyle{branch}=[fill,shape=circle,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0pt]
    %Creating Blocks and Connection Nodes
    \node at (-2.5,0) (input) {$x[n]$};
    \node [block] (h1) {$h_1[n]$};
    \node [block, right of=h1] (h2) {$h_2[n]$};
    \node [sum, right of=h2] (sum) {};
    \node at (sum) (plus) {{\footnotesize$+$}};
    \node at (5,0) (output) {$y[n]$};
    \path (h1) -- coordinate (med) (h2);
    \path (input) -- coordinate(branch1) (h1);
    \node [block, below of=med] (h3) {$h_3[n]$};
    %Conecting Blocks
    \begin{scope}[line width=1pt]
         \draw[->] (input) -- (h1);
         \draw[->] (h1) -- (h2);
         \draw[->] (h2) -- (sum);
         \draw[->] (sum) -- (output);
         \draw[->] (branch1) node[branch] {} |- (h3);
         \draw[->] (h3) -| (sum);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Simple Block Diagrams]

In the document preamble add `\usepackage{tikz}`, I know that the code seems a little difficult but it is.

The operating principle of the package is: drawn nodes over a grid, and every node can contain a figure or simply it work as a connection node. The package manual is a very good documentation about it, see for help.

Comment: Maybe adding a simple code example would help.

Comment: In a moment! :)

Comment: \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=latex'] while making pdf, here process stops and says that arrow end type latex is unknown.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot, you must use `\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}` in the preamble. See corrected code, copy and paste with it. :)