# How to use usetikzlibrary{dsp,chains}

Tags: tikzlibrary

I, i'm trying to draw a block diagram with tikz like discribed the link below 
http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/fir-filter/

but when i compile the code, i get a text error :

I can't find 'tikzlibrarydsp.code.tek' \usetikzlibrary{dsp,chains}.

Does somebody know how to overcome this

Comment: There is a link that says *Download the digital signal processing library: `tikz-dsp.zip`* in the link....

Answer (score 4):

I see two possible solutions:

1. Download the library files tikz-dsp.zip as written on the webpage you referred to.
2. Use alternative approach such as

   - http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/noise-shaper/ or
   - [Is there a predefined bandpass filter block in tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200235/is-there-a-predefined-bandpass-filter-block-in-tikz) or
   - [Drawing filter banks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56436/drawing-filter-banks)

Answer (score 1):

- Download the library files `tikz-dsp.zip` as written on the webpage you referred to.
- Drop the `library/tex/latex/tikz-dsp` folder in `~/texmf/tex/latex/` (Linux) or `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/` (Mac)
- Run `hashtex` in the terminal

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `hashtex` is not required for `~/texmf/tex/latex`; and on the Mac one can use `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex`